# Haskell Labeled AST: No instance for (Show1 (Label a)), How to construct an instance?

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, recursive-datastructures, deriving

I want to have an annotated AST, so I defined those recursive data structures
using `Fix`:

```
data Term a 
  = Abstraction Name a
  | Application a a
  | Variable Name
  deriving (Read,Show,Eq,Functor,Foldable,Traversable)

data Label a b 
  = Label a (Term b)
  deriving (Read,Show,Eq,Functor,Foldable,Traversable)

newtype Labeled a 
  = Labeled (Fix (Label a))
  deriving (Show)
```

I want to be able to `show` a `Labeled a`, but the compiler is not happy:

> ```
> No instance for (Show1 (Label a))  
> arising from the first field of `Labeled' (type `Fix (Label a)')
> ```

What is the class `Show1` and how do I define the appropriate instance to be able to show the `Labeled a` ?

Comment: `Show1` appears to be defined in `Data.Functor.Classes`. `Label` in `Labeled (Fix (Label a))` is partially applied, which I think is what `Show1` is intended to address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Show1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#t:Show1) is the class of what you might call "higher-order showables": type constructors which are showable whenever their argument is showable. For the purposes of fast-and-loose reasoning, you can think of `Show1` as being declared roughly like this (see also [`showsPrec1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#v:showsPrec1)):

```
class Show1 f where
    show1 :: Show a => f a -> String
```

Here's another inaccurate-but-useful way to think about `Show1`. I'm using [the `constraints` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints)'s ["entailment" operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9.1/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t::-45-) to declare that `f a` should be an instance of `Show` whenever `a` is. This model is a bit simpler but perhaps less practical.

```
class Show1 f where
    show1 :: Show a :- Show (f a)
```

Anyway, `Fix :: (* -> *) -> *` is showable if its argument is a higher-order showable. From [the source code](https://github.com/ekmett/recursion-schemes/blob/fec353466c96c6a7e34dd4fbe641cf4e289771b8/Data/Functor/Foldable.hs#L467-L471):

```
instance Show1 f => Show (Fix f) where
  showsPrec d (Fix a) =
    showParen (d >= 11)
      $ showString "Fix "
      . showsPrec1 11 a
```

The authors of `recursion-schemes` could have used `StandaloneDeriving` to write their `Show` instance...

```
deriving instance Show (f (Fix f)) => Show (Fix f)
```

... but this context requires `UndecidableInstances`.

The easiest way to write a `Show1` instance for a given functor is to use [the `deriving-compat` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-compat)'s [Template Haskell helper](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-compat-0.3.6/docs/Text-Show-Deriving.html#v:deriveShow1).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Text.Show.Deriving
import Data.Functor.Foldable


type Name = String
data Term a 
    = Abstraction Name a
    | Application a a
    | Variable Name
    deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

deriveShow1 ''Term

data Label a b = Label a (Term b)
    deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

deriveShow1 ''Label

newtype Labeled a = Labeled (Fix (Label a)) deriving (Show)
```

This'll generate the following instances,

```
instance Show1 Term
instance Show a => Show1 (Label a)
```

giving you exactly what you want for `Labeled`'s derived instance:

```
instance Show a => Show (Labeled a)
```

(PS. Have you considered using a library like [`bound`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound) to manage names and binders in your term language?)